# Is there any way to get the values of a row from sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I know that sap.ui.table.Table lets you uses MultiToggle selectionMode. This adds a column with check boxes. Is there any way to use that check box to select a row and get that row value in my controller. I define my table control in a xml viw not in my controller. Using this setup would it be possible to retrieve a single row and get the values for the row. each row has a nested text area and label.

Here is my view

```
    <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table"
    controllerName="ariba.so.kaaguidedassistance.controller.GuidedAssistance" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
    <Page title="Guided Assistance Flow Page">
        <content>
            <Toolbar id="toolbar1">
                <Button text="update" press="onSubmit"></Button>
                <Button text="add Guided Assistance QA" press="onAddGAQA"></Button>
                <Button text="add Guided Assistance Keywords QA" press="onAddGAKQA"></Button>
                <Button text="delete" press="onNavigateDelete"></Button>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
            </Toolbar>
            <t:Table id="GAQA" rows="{guidedAssistanceGA>/data}" title="Guided Assistance QA" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCount="7">
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="ID"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Label text="{guidedAssistanceGA>ID}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="value_long"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="value_long" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>value_long}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Type"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="type" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Type}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Action"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Action" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Action}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button1"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button1" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button1}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button2"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button2" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button2}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button3"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button3" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button3}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button4"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button4" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button4}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button5"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button5" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button5}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Button6"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Button6" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Button6}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Active_Flag"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Active_Flag" value="{guidedAssistanceGA>Active_Flag}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
            </t:Table>
            <Toolbar id="toolbar2">
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
            </Toolbar>
            <t:Table id="GAKQA" rows="{guidedAssistanceGAK>/data}" title="Guided Assistance Keywords QA" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCount="7">
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Flow_ID"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Label text="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Flow_ID}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Keywords"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Keywords" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Keywords}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Intersection1"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Intersection1" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Intersection1}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Intersection2"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Intersection2" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Intersection2}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Logic_Group"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Logic_Group" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Logic_Group}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Logic_Order"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Logic_Order" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Logic_Order}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="Points"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <TextArea id="Points" value="{guidedAssistanceGAK>Points}" width="100%"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="11rem">
                    <Label text="ID"/>
                    <t:template>
                        <Label text="{guidedAssistanceGAK>ID}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
            </t:Table>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

I expect to retrieve the value for one of the rows in my controller. The value is in my label and text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take a look in the API documentation of sap.ui.table. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/getContextByIndex

You can use *getSelectedIndex* or *getSelectedIndices* to determine which lines are currently selected.
The method *getContextByIndex* gives you than the object for one row with all values.